# HERE Maps API with JQuery UI Dialog in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I’ve a problem when I use HERE Maps API in a web page that contain a JQuery UI Dialog widget. The problem occurred in Chrome browser. After opening and closing the Dialog widget, if I try to zoom or panning, the map is not correctly refreshed and  the console shows the following errors :

```
Coroutine 'nokia.maps.map.render.p2d.Engine#_renderCo' aborted abnormally with exception base.js:159
TypeError: undefined is not a function base.js:159
```

I get this error in Safari browser, too. That works without any error with Firefox or Internet Explorer. This error occured with the version 2.5.4 of HERE API, but not with the previous version 2.5.3.

The following web page shows the problem in Chrome browser :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HERE map with JQuery UI dialog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div><button id="bOpenDialog">open dialog</button></div>
    <div id="mapContainer" style="width:400px;height:250px;"></div>
    <div id="dialog" title="Test dialog">
        <p>Dialog content.</p>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.4/jsl.js?with=maps"></script>
    <script>
        nokia.Settings.set("app_id", "APP_ID");
        nokia.Settings.set("app_code", "APP_CODE");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bOpenDialog').click(function(){
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
             $("#dialog").dialog({
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen:false
            });
            var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(
                document.getElementById("mapContainer"), {
                    zoomLevel: 10,
                    center: [52.51, 13.4],
                    components : [new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()]
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After page loading, the map will work fine, but when the Dialog is opened and closed, the error will occur.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you still see this error? Does it happen with jQuery 1.10.4 only or does it happen in 1.12.1 too?